# Скрипты jQuery в верстке

Tags: jquery

Вопрос по моменту, увиденному в чужой верстке. В ней скрипты jQuery не собраны в head, а разбросаны по верстке в тех местах, где они используются (слайдеры и прочие элементы). Такое расположение скриптов ошибкой, как я понимаю, не является, хотя затрудняет чтение кода, но каждый скрипт начинается с

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

не является ли ошибкой вызов этой функции много раз? не приводит ли это к каким-либо проблемам?

Comment: Нет, это не ошибка и не приводит ни к каким проблемам. А разбросаны они могут быть по той причине, что кто-то додумался подгружать часть html-кода вместе с JS, код которого должен отвечать за работу подгруженной части html.

Comment: @Deonis, понятно, спасибо за объяснения =)